# Updating with GitExtensions and using Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am using GitExtensions to enlist in source code hosted on codeplex.com. So I have a local version on my desktop of this open source code which I want to privately test (i.e., I am not contributing anything back to that source code).

I obviously can pull major changes, so that if the source I had yesterday was 1.0 and today 1.1 comes out I can just update locally.

Now, I am thinking to put this source code that I am privately testing on Visual Studio Online so that I can access it on multiple computers (work, home, etc.).

I can set up VSO with no problem. My question is more rather if it's okay to continue pulling changes into the source using GitExtensions (when there are updates to that source code, i.e., 1.0 is what I have then 1.1 comes out) and then expect VS2013 to see those changes which I can then publish to VSO? Does this necessitate selecting Git as the version control when I am creating a new team project on VSO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to select Git as your version control. It will also help if you name your Team Project the same as the git repo (not required, but it will be a bit easier).

With your local git repo you can have multiple remotes that you push/pull code to. So in your case you'd have one remote for codeplex, and one for VSO.

Reference on git remotes here:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Comment: Thanks, explanation helped, particularly about remotes.